# Were students allowed to take their pets to Hogsmeade?

Tags: harry-potter

I never saw them bring their pets with them for the Hogsmeade trips, so I was wondering if they were allowed to. It'd be nice bringing a cat along just to be somewhere aside from the school.

Comment: Ron is told “get yourself down to Hogsmeade and buy a new rat” when he loses Scabbers; the implication is that there’s a pet shop in Hogsmeade. If so, students would probably be allowed to take their pets to the village, in case they needed veterinary assistance or similar.

Comment: @alexwlchan - This looks like a pretty reasonable answer right there.

Comment: Well, why should I bring my cat, if it can go there by itself? The pets are free to go everywhere on their own, so there is no need to bring them specifically to Hogsmeade. And I want to see how you want to drag a poor cat somewhere by force...

Answer (score 6):

**I think they were probably allowed to take pets to Hogsmeade.**

After Ron loses Scabbers, the twins tell him he can buy a new rat in Hogsmeade:

> “Oh, come on, Ron, get yourself down to Hogsmeade and buy a new rat, what’s the point of moaning?”
>
> — *Prisoner of Azkaban*, chapter 13 (*Gryffindor Versus Ravenclaw*)

The implication is that there’s a pet shop in Hogsmeade (I think it’s unlikely a shop that only sold rats would do be sustainable). This shop probably provides veterinary assistance to anybody who brings their animals in – both the students of Hogwarts and the residents of Hogsmeade. We see no evidence that this service is provided in-school, and any villagers with pets would need it too.

Often a vet needs to see the animal in question, so students would probably be allowed to take pets into Hogsmeade, if only for this reason.

Comment: Students are allowed to buy new pets in Hogsmeade, but might not be allowed to take them to there. It wouldn't be the weirdest rule in the series :)

Comment: Also the veterinary assistance is provided by the teacher of magical creatures/game keeper. In Order of the Phoenix Harry brings Hedwig to professor Grubbly-Plank because of her broken wing.